# Error Handling in VBScript with SAP through assigning an output variable and disabling pop-up

Tags: error-handling, vbscript, rpa, automationanywhere

**Summary:** I am using RPA software(Automation Anywhere) to execute a VBS script. If a pop-up shows while the script runs then RPA is not able to catch the error because the Run Script Command has not finished due to the pop up. I have a variable vErrorVBS which is equal to 1 in RPA.

**Objective:** I am trying to write some error handling in the VBS script through the variable assigned in RPA. I want to catch an error if it happens then assign the vErrorVBS = 2 then quit the script with no pop ups.

**Problem:** If I use On Error Resume Next, the pop up does not show, but the variable does not get assigned. I am struggling on how to write the error handling part in VBS.

The structure of the code that I think would work is as follows,

```
vErrorVBS = WScript.Arguments(0)

session.findById("...ID....").maximize 'some SAP Script line
session.findById("....ID....").press   'some SAP Script line
'Some error happens in the prevous line then the error handling would be something like this
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      vErrorVBS = 2
      Err.Clear
      WScript.Quit
End If
```

This code didn't not assign the variable or disable the pop up.
I am not sure what the syntax should be for the inside of the If Statement, and where to place the If Statement. Should it be after each possible line where an error occurs, or can it be at the very end to catch any error that occurs?

Comment: Thank you Lankymart. I updated my question with the code I tried, but it still isn't doing what I need it to. The variable remains assigned to 1 and the pop-up still shows.

Comment: Where is `On Error Resume Next` in the sample code? You can't use the `Err` object without it.

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry, its there. right under the variable deceleration of vErrorVBS, and above the first `session.findById("...ID....").maximize` . Should it only be at the top because right now the pop-up doesnt show, but the variable remains the same

Answer (score 0):

VBScript doesn't automatically return the variable values back to AA.

You have to specify `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine vErrorVBS` before `WScript.Quit`
to return the value back to AA so that your value will be captured in return variable specified in `Run Script` command

Comment: I tried the `WScript.echo`, but that puts my variable = 2 and displays it in a pop up. I am trying to avoid the pop up. I was reading online, and thought I can put `vErrorVBS = 2` then under that `Err.Clear` then `WScript.Quit`. This seems to work, but now I think the `Err.Clear` is resetting the error value to 0, so I don't know if AA will get the output variable of vErrorVBS =  2

Comment: My bad. It should be `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine`

Comment: yeah, thank you Tanmay. That worked out